Firestore-export .bat file to obtain .json files get stuck
I have a .bat file scheduled daily that runs some commands to obtain .json files from my Firestore Database through a key.json file that i got from my project settings, it usually works well, but some days it just gets stuck and doesn't finish the whole commands. This is how it looks like, I hope you can help me fixing this, because I use the json files to daily update a PowerBi dashboard (Is updated daily with the files located in the folder that is synchronized with OneDrive). As I said, it works most of the times its executed, but some days it just gets stuck, and right now I haven't been able to run it completely since 3 days ago. By the way, if anyone knows a way to do the same task without needing to have my computer on, it'd be great. I have tried to change the key file, to change my internet connection. I expect to know why this happen and to run it softly every time.
@echo off
call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\pagos.json -n pagos --prettyPrint
call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\planpagos.json -n planPagos --prettyPrint

call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\usuarios.json -n sellers --prettyPrint
call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\separaciones.json -n ordSep --prettyPrint
call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\Planes/planpagosL01.json -n planPagos/L01/pagosEsperados --prettyPrint
call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\Planes/planpagosL02.json -n planPagos/L02/pagosEsperados --prettyPrint
call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\Planes/planpagosL03.json -n planPagos/L03/pagosEsperados --prettyPrint
call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\Planes\planpagosL04.json -n planPagos/L04/pagosEsperados --prettyPrint
...
call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\Planes\planpagosL67.json -n planPagos/L67/pagosEsperados --prettyPrint
call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\lotes.json -n lotes --prettyPrint
call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\cotizaciones.json -n quotes --prettyPrint
call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\clientes.json -n customers --prettyPrint

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value') do set "timestamp=%%I"

REM Extract individual components of the date and time
set "year=%timestamp:~0,4%"
set "month=%timestamp:~4,2%"
set "day=%timestamp:~6,2%"
set "hour=%timestamp:~8,2%"
set "minute=%timestamp:~10,2%"

REM Create formatted timestamp
set "formatted_timestamp=%day%-%month%-%year% %hour%:%minute%"

REM Create JSON file with timestamp
echo {"timestamp": "%formatted_timestamp%"} > "C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\hora.json"


I have no idea what firestore-export is supposed to be, because Windows doesn't come with a utility or script with that basename, and cmd.exe doesn't have a command with that name either. Based upon only the parameter like arguments it is using, I'm going to assume that it is not really another batch file, i.e. firestore-export.cmd or firestore-export.bat. The call command is only for batch files, so if firestore-export is not another batch file please remove all of those call prefixes, and preferably add the full paths and extension, e.g. "P:\ath To\firestore-export.ext" ...

First step to solving this problem:
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

call :firestore pagos pagos
call :firestore planpagos planpagos
call :firestore usuarios sellers
call :firestore separaciones ordSep
FOR /L %%e IN (101,1,167) DO call :firestoreplan %%e
call :firestore lotes lotes 
call :firestore cotizaciones quotes
call :firestore clientes customers

GOTO :EOF

:firestoreplan
SET /a iteration=%1
CALL :firestore Planes\planpagosL%iteration:~-2% planPagos\L%iteration:~-2%\pagosEsperados
GOTO :eof

:firestore
ECHO call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\%1.json -n %2 --prettyPrint
GOTO :eof

Note that I've assumed that the last few lines (the wmic processing onwards) are working properly and I've omitted)
I've changed all /s to windows-standard backslashes.
The objective here is to make all of the firestore-export lines pass through one line.
The code merely echoes the firestore-export lines to the console. This is deliberate; it allows the processing that the routine proposes to do to be displayed for verification. After verification, remove the echo before the call keyword and it should process identically to your original (when you've added the wmic appendix, of course).
Next step is to determine which line is failing and why that line is failing.
The which-line is easy:
:firestore
ECHO %*>>alogfilename
call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\%1.json -n %2 --prettyPrint
GOTO :eof

which will report the failing process's parameters to the file alogfilename (which can be any filename you choose, within reason).
So now the big question: Why?
firestore-export may be stalling and requesting a user action, or perhaps it's waiting for some condition to be met.
In the first case, it will probably generate a console message and wait for a response from the keyboard. You may be able to capture this with
:firestore
ECHO %*>>alogfilename
call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\%1.json -n %2 --prettyPrint 2>&1 >errorfilename
GOTO :eof

where errorfilename should capture the message being generated (and the last entry of alogfilename provides the data on the item being processed)
It's possible that echo y|firestore-export… would automatically enter y as a response to this response; no guarantees.
Perhaps the process is waiting on a file to become available, or the file may be open to another process - any of a number of scenarios.
Perhaps
:firestore
ECHO %*>>alogfilename
if not exist "C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\%1.json" echo "C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\%1.json" does not exist>>errormessagesfile&goto :eof
for %%y in ("C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\%1.json") do if %%~zy==0 echo "C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\%1.json" is empty>>errormessagesfile&goto :eof
call firestore-export -a C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\key.json -b C:\Users\Javier\OneDrive\Albaterra\%1.json -n %2 --prettyPrint 2>&1 >errorfilename
GOTO :eof

may provide clues in errormessagesfile - remembering that if a process is still writing to a file, its length is likely to be reported as zero.

Thank you!  It looks like it was a problem related to the internet stability, because I ran the same process in another computer connected via ethernet cable, and ran smooth as butter, same if I'm next to the router, is weird, but at the end this will be running only in my client's pc, that is connected via cable, and is already 2 weeks since installed, and running perfect. Thank you for your help!
